# Get 0 to 9999 in PHP using FOR EACH and Array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

How would I print all values 0...9999 using an array of `$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);` ? No clue, please help.

Comment: Do you have to use `foreach()`? Because this sounds like a job for an ordinary `for()`.

Comment: It's pretty easy to print all values from 0 to 9999 even without the array. Not sure why you want it. Interview question? Homework?

Comment: Wow, this is embarrassing. My answer was the top answer yet I just realized it had nothing to do with the question. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This would seem like an homework assignment, so some thinking of your own should apply. Example below is *specifically* strict to the assignment, it is in no way the best solution for just displaying all number between 0 and 9999.

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

foreach($array as $value_1)
    foreach($array as $value_2)
        foreach($array as $value_3)
            foreach($array as $value_4)
                echo $value_1.$value_2.$value_3.$value_4.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question helpfully (i.e. with constructive advice).

Comment: You should consider his answer accepted by checking his answer as the accepted solution so that this question is solved. :)

Comment: I don't think this meets the requirements.  This would produce 0000, 0001...9999.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
foreach ($array as $a) {
  foreach ($array as $b) {
    foreach ($array as $c) {
      foreach ($array as $d) {

        if ($a) echo $a;
        if ($a || $b) echo $b;
        if ($a || $b || $c) echo $c;

        echo $d. "<br />\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

foreach ($array as $i) {
   foreach ($array as $j) {
      foreach ($array as $k) {
         foreach ($array as $l) {
            print $i*1000+$j*100+$k*10+$l."\n";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Smells like a homework assignment ;)